# iOS9: UITableViewCell building before returned from cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios9

My code still works perfectly in iOS8 but in iOS9 the cell is somehow built before `cellForRowAtIndexPath` returns the UITableViewCell O.o

```
// in my TableView.swift file:
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // It seems the cell.swift file is run here, breaking at layoutSubViews (below)
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! QSMyCellNEW

    cell.delegate = self
    cell.QJoinObject = myQJoinObjects[indexPath.row] as! PFObject

    print(cell.QJoinObject) // all data present

    return cell
}



// in my tableViewCell.swift file:
class QSMyCellNEW: UITableViewCell {

var QJoinObject: PFObject!
}
.
.
.
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    print(QJoinObject) // breaks - unwraps nil optional
}
```

Comment: make QJoinObject optional like var QJoinObject: PFObject?

Comment: QJoinObject is a `PFObject`? So I take it you are retrieving them from parse.com? Are you sure that you are receiving that data in iOS 9 environment?

Comment: Yes, pretty sure I am retrieving. If you look at the code above and my comments in it you can see that I am verifying the data is there with a simple `print` before returning the cell. Furthermore, if it was not there `numberOfRowsInSection` would return 0 and it would never try to call the cell.swift (and in turn not try to unwrap).

Comment: Actually, I added a print inside the cell.swift `layoutSubviews` method and even with the object declared as `var QJoinObject: PFObject?` it is still nil

Comment: Update: the debugger shows that the cell.swift file is being called before `cellForRowAtIndexPath` - which means the cell is somehow being called before the viewController even requests it be built...

Comment: I may have the issue as yours, when I use `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, please check my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34524545/ios9-why-layoutsubviews-of-custom-uitableviewcell-is-called-in-dequeuereusablec