# iOS9, why layoutSubviews of custom UITableViewCell is called in dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath if systemLayoutSizeFittingSize is used

Tags: ios, uitableview

> a **more specific description** of my question: in iOS9, why `layoutSubviews` of my custom UITableViewCell is called by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath`, if `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` is used to calculate the cell height in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`?
>
> Therefore, `layoutSubviews` is called before it is returned by `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, and I can no longer use `layoutSubviews` to determine whether the cell is on screen or not, and there are couple of issues with constraints handling.

For complex custom UITableViewCells, I prefer to use `layoutSubview` method for code that should run **after** the constraint are calculated and applied. 
As the custom UITableViewCell is **complex**, I use `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath` to calculate the height by auto-Layout.
This works perfectly in iOS8, but is broken in iOS9.

To dig out the root cause, I made a minimal project, including a custom UITableViewCell, which has a custom label with constraints set:

```
class testCell : UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelTest: UILabel!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        print("testCell - init:coder")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        print("testCell - layoutSubviews ")
    }

    func setLabelText(text : String) {
        self.labelTest?.text = text
    }
}
```

and tableView's dataSource:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("testCell") as? testCell {
        cell.setLabelText(String(indexPath.row))
        print(" tableview systemLayoutSizeFittingSize for \(indexPath.row)")
        let size = cell.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(CGSizeMake(tableView.bounds.size.width, 1))
        return size.height
    }

    return 0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let char = indexPath.row > 0 ? "" : ""
    print(char+char+char+char+char+char+char+char+char+char+char+char+char+char+char+char+char+char)
    print("tableview start... dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier for \(indexPath.row)")
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("testCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    print("tableview end... dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier for \(indexPath.row)")
    print(char+char+char+char+char+char+char+char+char+char+char+char+char+char+char+char+char+char)
    if let cell = cell as? testCell {
        cell.setLabelText(String(indexPath.row))
    }
    return cell
}
```

The logs shows that `layoutSubviews` is called inside dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath

> testCell - init:coder
>    tableview systemLayoutSizeFittingSize for 0
>   testCell - init:coder
>    tableview systemLayoutSizeFittingSize for 0
>   testCell - init:coder
>    tableview systemLayoutSizeFittingSize for 0
>   testCell - init:coder
>    tableview systemLayoutSizeFittingSize for 0
>   
>   tableview start... dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier for 0
>   testCell - init:coder
>   testCell - init:coder
>    tableview systemLayoutSizeFittingSize for 0
>   testCell - layoutSubviews 
>   tableview end... dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier for 0
>   
>   testCell - init:coder
>    tableview systemLayoutSizeFittingSize for 0
>   testCell - layoutSubviews

Let's focus on the logs between the 2 lines of :

> tableview start... dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier for 0
>   testCell - init:coder
>   testCell - init:coder
>    tableview systemLayoutSizeFittingSize for 0
>   testCell - layoutSubviews 
>   tableview end... dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier for 0

- analyse:
      * the first *testCell - init:coder* is called by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath` which is called by `cellForRowAtIndexPath`
      * the second *testCell - init:coder* is called by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` which is called by `heightForRowAtIndexPath`
      * and I set a breakpoint at *testCell - layoutSubviews*, and confirmed it  is called by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath` which is called by `cellForRowAtIndexPath`
- conclude:
  For unknown reason, the `layoutSubviews` of the custom UITableViewCell is called by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

## TO FIND SOLUTIONS

1. The first solution lies in function: `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`
   If I **manually calculate the height of the cell** instead of using `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize`, it works! `layoutSubviews` won't be called by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath`.
   But this method is not handy, since the calculation of the cell height might be toooooo complex.
   Below is the modified code and log:

   ```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
       return 100 // might be a very complex calculation
   }
   ```

   > tableview start... dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier for 0
   >   testCell - init:coder
   >   tableview end... dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier for 0
   >   
   >   testCell - layoutSubviews
2. The second solution lies in function: `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`
   I tried to use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` instead of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath`, the log below shows that `layoutSubviews` in not called directly in `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, but it is still called in `tableView:_configureCellForDisplay` (not sure of the timing). I can't confirm it is a solution or not.
   Anyways, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath` is the recommended method other than `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. If I would, I still prefer the former one.

   > testCell - init:coder
   >    tableview systemLayoutSizeFittingSize for 0
   >   testCell - init:coder
   >    tableview systemLayoutSizeFittingSize for 0
   >   testCell - init:coder
   >    tableview systemLayoutSizeFittingSize for 0
   >   testCell - init:coder
   >    tableview systemLayoutSizeFittingSize for 0
   >   
   >   tableview start... dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier for 0
   >   testCell - init:coder
   >   tableview end... dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier for 0
   >   
   >   testCell - init:coder
   >    tableview systemLayoutSizeFittingSize for 0
   >   testCell - layoutSubviews 
   >   testCell - layoutSubviews

## QUESTIONS:

Although I've found 2 solutions, neither of them is satisfying.
The best approach is that I can still use `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` to calculate the cell height, and use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath` to get a valid cell.
The only problem is that I need to confirm that `layoutSubviews` is not called prior to it is returned by function `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (in current case, it is called by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath` before it is returned by function `cellForRowAtIndexPath`), so that I can use this method for code that will run **after** the constraints on the cell are calculated and applied, and can confirm that when reaching `layoutSubviews`, the cell is already on screen.
Does anyone have any good idea?
Thanks.